# Unable to Select the month of a jquery datepicker using the Selenium

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium, datepicker

I am trying to select a custom date in the datepicker present in the jqueryui.com site, it is able to process the year , but the code that i written for the month is not working.Please find the code that i have used:-

```
private static void PickDate(WebDriver driver, String day, String mon, String year) throws Exception {
     while (year != driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText())
     {
         if (Integer.parseInt(year) < Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText()))
         {
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-prev")).click();
             System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
         }
         else if (Integer.parseInt(year) > Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText()))
         {
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-next")).click();
         }
     }  
     while (mon != (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
     {
         if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText() != "January")
         {
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-prev")).click();
         }
         if (mon != driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText())
         {
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-next")).click();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to select a date in the datepicker, I would rather use execute script than click back and forth. :)
Something like:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day))")
```

If you want to click on the previous/next button, then:

Because your code looks quite complicated, so I would like to provide another approach, which I believe that will be much simpler.

Notice that when you click on the previous/next button, it will move forward/backward by 1 month. So it's better if you firstly calculate how many months in difference between the date you want to select (month and year) and the current shown date on the DatePicker.

If you write in java, you can use something like:

```
YearMonth selectDate = YearMonth.of(year, month); // year, month are integer
int dp_Year = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText()); 
int dp_Month = // convert it yourself
YearMonth dp_Date = YearMonth.of(dp_Year, dp_Month);
int month_diff = dp_Date.until(selectDate, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
```

Based on month_diff and its sign (+ or -), you will know which button you need to click on and how many times.
I don't have java to try out, but I hope that the code above will work.

Comment: ,The jqueryui.com datepicker navigates by using the previous and the next buttons , so we need to write code which uses that functionality. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: So you want to test the previous and next buttons rather than select a date? I would write a method to select a date like I suggested above (for example, 03/12/2015, then have a test like: click twice on the next button, verify that the month and year should be Feb 2016. And a similar test for the previous button

Comment: I dont have much idea on Javascript , i wanted to write a code that will click on the previous or next buttons till it reaches the required year and month.Could you please help here ?